# Diagonal content with CSS Transform but with a vertical text as a content

Tags: html, css

i just trying to do a Diagonal content but with a vertical text as a content. You can see this effect, which i trying to do, here: http://unfold.no/ . And on this Link: http://codepen.io/Alanes/pen/GJvQmZ  you can see what i already tried to do. Is it posible to do this Diagonal content effect just with CSS or i need to do this effect with JS? I'll appreciate any Idea. Thank u very much!

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="container">
            <div class="box blue">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et </p>
            </div>
            <div class="box green">
                <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis 
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="box red">
                <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes
                </p>
            </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
#container{
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.box{
    width: 100%;
    height: 600px;
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg) scale(2.0);
  -webkit-transform:rotate(-45deg) scale(2.0);
    transform:rotate(-45deg) scale(2.0);
  -ms-transform-origin: 0% 0%; 
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
    transform-origin: 0% 0%;

}
.blue{
    background-color: blue;

}
.green{
    background-color: green;
}
.red{
    background-color: red;
}
p{
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg) scale(0.7);
  -webkit-transform:rotate(45deg) scale(0.7);
    transform:rotate(45deg) scale(0.7);
    width: 400px;
    padding: 80px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set them to 0 deg, as you are already rotating there divs. So by setting the P to 45 deg is just countering the rotation.

Example - https://jsfiddle.net/aj7dezze/

The example was done by setting the P to 0deg

```
    p{
        -ms-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(0.7);
        -webkit-transform:rotate(0deg) scale(0.7);
        transform:rotate(0deg) scale(0.7);
        width: 400px;
        padding: 80px;
    }
```

Comment: this is right.  sorry i make a wrong question.. i have 2 Problems: Problem number 1.- if you see the content: blue, green and red does not fill the Container at all. Problem number 2.- the content blue , green and red should not overlap.

Comment: @NardaP they will overlap, to remove it just add a margin-top to the boxes margin-top:248px; seemed to work well for me

Comment: @NardaP to answer your other question, I would recommend taking the rotate off but leave the scale on a looking at it, as you can see there is a lot of padding going on, I don't know how you want it so I can't help, but I would recommend making them look right first and then rotate the divs.

Comment: @NardaP You sorted it?